# Django error 'ManagerDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am relatively new to django and am running into the error 'ManagerDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter' when retrieving view 'dashboard' -- below is my view and model. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

**#views.py**

```
def dashboard(request):
    tabledata_totals = ''
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path)
    else:
        orgs = Profile.objects.values_list('assigned_org_ids', 'view_group').get(user_id=request.user.id)
        tabledata_totals = org_totals.objects.filter(org_id__in=orgs[0].split(',')).aggregate(
            sum('open_supplement_count'),
            sum('open_estimate_count'),
            sum('open_measurement_count'),
            sum('total_open_count'),
            sum('supplement_sent_to_ins'),
            sum('revised_scope_received_additional_items_needed'),
            sum('homeowner_permission_needed'),
            sum('three_calls_to_adjuster_without_response'),
            sum('spoke_to_adjuster'),
            sum('missing_documents_required_for_supplementation'),
            sum('wWaiting_on_a_revised_scope'),
            sum('estimate_created_and_sent_to_customer'),
            sum('deal_in'),
            sum('supplement_complete'),
            sum('eagleview_measurements'),
            sum('confirmed_received'),
            sum('confirmed_assigned_to_adjuster'),
            sum('additional_documentation_needed')
            )
    return render(request, 'HTML/dashboard.html', {'data': tabledata_totals})
```

**#models.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
class org_totals(models.Model):
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    org_id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    open_supplement_count = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    open_estimate_count = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    open_measurement_count = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_open_count = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Supplement_Sent_to_Ins = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Revised_Scope_Received_Additional_Items_Needed = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Homeowner_Permission_Needed = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    three_Calls_to_Adjuster_Without_Response = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Spoke_to_Adjuster = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Missing_Documents_Required_for_Supplementation = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Waiting_on_a_Revised_Scope = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Estimate_Created_and_Sent_to_Customer = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Deal_In = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Supplement_Complete = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Eagleview_Measurements = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Confirmed_Received = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Confirmed_Assigned_to_Adjuster = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Additional_Documentation_Needed = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'org_open_totals'
```

Comment: I am pretty new to this myself so bare with me.

It seems that the `ManagerDescriptor` deals with the Manager for this Model. Being that Model Managers deal with "table-level" functionality I would venture to guess that the `managed=False` is causing tables not to be written and therefore you have no access to a filter for a table that does not exist (?). Have you tried removing `managed=False`?

Comment: Also, this doesn't pertain to the question but a few things that might help out.. Python convention for naming classes is CamelCase while methods and functions use all lowercase with underscores. And the `@loginrequired` decorator can be applied to the view then in your settings you can define `LOGIN_URL = 'login'` rather than specifying it in the decorator.

Comment: Yeah, these are actually coming from a postresql view... the view is just a table of totals. So, I dont think the managed = False would be the cause.. although I supposee it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: I checked the things you had listed above and cleaned up the punctuation -- however, no effect on the error

Comment: I just realized that as of adding this new model & view none of my querysets are working -- they are all returning the same ManageDesriptor error...

Comment: So, I rolled back both postresql db and django project and then readded everything and it works. Almost. I realize this is a separate question but I am now getting error 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'   --- for the sum part of my query... any help there would be appreciated..

Comment: if anyone knows how to use that sum in the queryset please let me know...  otherwise, I just did it this way and its working. (removed the sum for each of the fields...   and then in the result: [code] return render(request, 'HTML/dashboard.html', {'data': [sum(x) for x in zip(*tabledata_totals)]}) [code]